# Убрать отступ у изображения в контейнере

Tags: html, css

Ребят, у меня есть контейнер, а в нём лежит изображение. У изображения в `container-2` есть отступ сверху (выделил красным), который я никак не могу убрать и не могу найти причину, почему он там есть.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
html,
body,
h1 {
  font-family: 'Gamja Flower', cursive;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

header {
  height: 110px;
  color: #edeff1;
}

nav,
.menu {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  font-size: 22px;
}

.menu li {
  display: block;
  margin-right: 40px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-left: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

li:nth-child(3) {
  margin-top: 21px;
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #dd4b2b;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 8px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
}

.menu li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #31353e;
}

.main {
  width: 100%;
}

.image {
  position: relative;
}

.image img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1000px;
}

.image .captions {
  left: 5%;
  right: 5%;
  bottom: 55%;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 0.5;
}

.image .captions .line-1 {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.line-1 h1 {
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}

.image .captions .line-2 {
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 26px;
}

.main-2 .icons {
  color: white;
  left: 15%;
  right: 5%;
  bottom: 25%;
  position: absolute;
}

.icons img {
  width: 110px;
  height: 110px;
}

.main-2 .icons-2 {
  color: white;
  left: 50%;
  right: 5%;
  bottom: 23%;
  position: absolute;
}

.icons-2 img {
  width: 110px;
  height: 110px;
}

.main-2 .icons-3 {
  color: white;
  left: 80%;
  right: 5%;
  bottom: 21%;
  position: absolute;
}

.icons-3 img {
  width: 110px;
  height: 110px;
}

.button {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 9%;
  left: 43%;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 22px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #61362c;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding: 15px;
  width: 145px;
}

.container {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 900px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #edeff1;
  text-align: center;
}

.container h1 {
  padding-top: 80px;
  font-size: 52px;
}

div.images {
  margin-top: 87px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.first h2 {
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.first p {
  text-align: center;
}

.second h2 {
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.second p {
  text-align: center;
}

.third h2 {
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.third p {
  text-align: center;
}

.button2 {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 22px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #66686f;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding: 15px;
  width: 195px;
  margin: 40px auto;
}

.container-2 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 350px;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.container-2 img {
  background-color: red;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Gamja+Flower" rel="stylesheet">


<header>
  <nav>
    <div class="nav">
      <ul class="menu">
        <li><a href="#">Fusce at</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Facilisis</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Ante donec</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Blandit rhoncus</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Placerat</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>
<div class="main">
  <div class="image">
    <img src="Layer1.png" />
    <div class="captions">
      <div class="line-1">
        <h1>Integer at tortor ut magna</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="line-2">
        <p>finibus lobortis sed quis tellus.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="main-2">
      <div class="icons">
        <img src="Layer 2.png">
        <h2>Tincidont</h2>
        Phasellus arcu justo, ullamcorper non diam sit amet,<br> luctus condimentum metus. Nullam tempus egestas<br> efficitur. Sed quam dolor.
      </div>
      <div class="icons-2">
        <img src="Layer 3.png">
        <h2>Duis Bibendum</h2>
        Ut arcu arcu, faucibus eu risus blandit, pulvinar<br> viverra justo. Phasellus arcu justo, ullamcorper<br> non diam sit amet, luctus condimentum metus. In<br> hac habitasse platea dictumst.
      </div>
      <div class="icons-3">
        <img src="Layer 4.png">
        <h2>Donec Ligula</h2>
        Nullam tempus egestas efficitur. Sed quam dolor,<br> vulputate sed mattis et, sodales quis orci. Ut arcu<br> arcu,faucibus eu risus blandit,.
      </div>
    </div>
    <a class="button" href="#">Read more</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <h1>Our news</h1>
  <div class="images">
    <div class="first">
      <img src="Layer 5.png">
      <h2>Lorem ipsum</h2>
      <p>Est a elit scelerisque vestibulum. Donec est sem,<br> lobortis sit amet imperdiet vel, pretium lobortis<br> erat. Nulla vitae hendrerit odio.</p>
      <a class="button2" href="#">Read more</a>
    </div>
    <div class="second">
      <img src="Layer 6.png">
      <h2>Lorem ipsum</h2>
      <p>Est a elit scelerisque vestibulum. Donec est sem,<br> lobortis sit amet imperdiet vel, pretium lobortis<br> erat. Nulla vitae hendrerit odio.</p>
      <a class="button2" href="#">Read more</a>
    </div>
    <div class="third">
      <img src="Layer 7.png">
      <h2>Lorem ipsum</h2>
      <p>Est a elit scelerisque vestibulum. Donec est sem,<br> lobortis sit amet imperdiet vel, pretium lobortis<br> erat. Nulla vitae hendrerit odio.</p>
      <a class="button2" href="#">Read more</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container-2">
  <img src="Layer 8.png">
</div>
```

Comment: Попробуй на изображение `vertical-align: top`

Comment: у Вас полоска на картинке, очевидно

Comment: обычно пишут для тега img{bisplay:block;} а по умолчанию img inline-block т.е имеются отступы

Answer (score 0):

Полоски не вижу - возможно у нас на картинке есть прозрачный фон сверху

```css
html,
body,
h1 {
  font-family: 'Gamja Flower', cursive;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

header {
  height: 110px;
  color: #edeff1;
}

nav,
.menu {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  font-size: 22px;
}

.menu li {
  display: block;
  margin-right: 40px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-left: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

li:nth-child(3) {
  margin-top: 21px;
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #dd4b2b;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 8px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
}

.menu li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #31353e;
}

.main {
  width: 100%;
}

.image {
  position: relative;
}

.image img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1000px;
}

.image .captions {
  left: 5%;
  right: 5%;
  bottom: 55%;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 0.5;
}

.image .captions .line-1 {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.line-1 h1 {
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}

.image .captions .line-2 {
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 26px;
}

.main-2 .icons {
  color: white;
  left: 15%;
  right: 5%;
  bottom: 25%;
  position: absolute;
}

.icons img {
  width: 110px;
  height: 110px;
}

.main-2 .icons-2 {
  color: white;
  left: 50%;
  right: 5%;
  bottom: 23%;
  position: absolute;
}

.icons-2 img {
  width: 110px;
  height: 110px;
}

.main-2 .icons-3 {
  color: white;
  left: 80%;
  right: 5%;
  bottom: 21%;
  position: absolute;
}

.icons-3 img {
  width: 110px;
  height: 110px;
}

.button {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 9%;
  left: 43%;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 22px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #61362c;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding: 15px;
  width: 145px;
}

.container {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 900px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #edeff1;
  text-align: center;
}

.container h1 {
  padding-top: 80px;
  font-size: 52px;
}

div.images {
  margin-top: 87px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.first h2 {
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.first p {
  text-align: center;
}

.second h2 {
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.second p {
  text-align: center;
}

.third h2 {
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.third p {
  text-align: center;
}

.button2 {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 22px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #66686f;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding: 15px;
  width: 195px;
  margin: 40px auto;
}

.container-2 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 350px;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.container-2 img {
  background-color: red;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Gamja+Flower" rel="stylesheet">


<header>
  <nav>
    <div class="nav">
      <ul class="menu">
        <li><a href="#">Fusce at</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Facilisis</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Ante donec</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Blandit rhoncus</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Placerat</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>
<div class="main">
  <div class="image">
    <img src="Layer1.png" />
    <div class="captions">
      <div class="line-1">
        <h1>Integer at tortor ut magna</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="line-2">
        <p>finibus lobortis sed quis tellus.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="main-2">
      <div class="icons">
        <img src="Layer 2.png">
        <h2>Tincidont</h2>
        Phasellus arcu justo, ullamcorper non diam sit amet,<br> luctus condimentum metus. Nullam tempus egestas<br> efficitur. Sed quam dolor.
      </div>
      <div class="icons-2">
        <img src="Layer 3.png">
        <h2>Duis Bibendum</h2>
        Ut arcu arcu, faucibus eu risus blandit, pulvinar<br> viverra justo. Phasellus arcu justo, ullamcorper<br> non diam sit amet, luctus condimentum metus. In<br> hac habitasse platea dictumst.
      </div>
      <div class="icons-3">
        <img src="Layer 4.png">
        <h2>Donec Ligula</h2>
        Nullam tempus egestas efficitur. Sed quam dolor,<br> vulputate sed mattis et, sodales quis orci. Ut arcu<br> arcu,faucibus eu risus blandit,.
      </div>
    </div>
    <a class="button" href="#">Read more</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <h1>Our news</h1>
  <div class="images">
    <div class="first">
      <img src="Layer 5.png">
      <h2>Lorem ipsum</h2>
      <p>Est a elit scelerisque vestibulum. Donec est sem,<br> lobortis sit amet imperdiet vel, pretium lobortis<br> erat. Nulla vitae hendrerit odio.</p>
      <a class="button2" href="#">Read more</a>
    </div>
    <div class="second">
      <img src="Layer 6.png">
      <h2>Lorem ipsum</h2>
      <p>Est a elit scelerisque vestibulum. Donec est sem,<br> lobortis sit amet imperdiet vel, pretium lobortis<br> erat. Nulla vitae hendrerit odio.</p>
      <a class="button2" href="#">Read more</a>
    </div>
    <div class="third">
      <img src="Layer 7.png">
      <h2>Lorem ipsum</h2>
      <p>Est a elit scelerisque vestibulum. Donec est sem,<br> lobortis sit amet imperdiet vel, pretium lobortis<br> erat. Nulla vitae hendrerit odio.</p>
      <a class="button2" href="#">Read more</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container-2">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/bmuVz.png">
</div>
```